# VisualStudioのプロジェクトをコマンドラインからcscでコンパイルするときのリソースの参照方法

Tags: c#

お世話になります。

VisualStudioで作成したC#のWindowsフォームアプリケーションを、
コマンドラインのcsc.exeでコンパイルしようと考えています。
こちら『http://mint.ldblog.jp/archives/20739054.html』のサイト様を参考に、
作成されたプロジェクトのフォルダの中の、bin,obj,Properties,Resources
などのフォルダとソースファイルが保存される場所の中に、
『csc /optimize+ /out:a.exe *.cs』のようなbatファイルを作成して
コンパイルしてみたのですが、『名前'Properties'は現在のコンテキストに
存在しません。』と怒られてしまいます。

当然と言えば当然なのですが、これを解決する方法を教えてください。
batファイルをどのように書き換えればよいのでしょうか。

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studioをお使いのようですので、メニューの[ツール]-[オプション]ダイアログの[[ビルド/実行]に[MSBuild プロジェクト ビルドの出力の詳細]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/cyhcc7zc(v=vs.100).aspx)があります。これを「最小」から「標準」に変更しますと出力ウィンドウに実際に実行したコマンドラインが表示されます。
これを参考にされるとBATへの記載すべき内容がわかるかと。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
今になって、MSBuildというものがあるということに気がついたのですが、
つまりはcsc.exeは『役に立たないから使う必要はない』のでしょうか。

最終的には、テキストエディタとコンパイラだけで、IDEと同等のものが
できるようになればと思っての質問なのですが、cscコンパイラにそこまでの
機能がないのなら、こちらのMSBuildを使うしかないようですね。

Comment: エラー内容はソースコードの問題ですが、質問タイトルにはリソースとあります。ところでcscはC#コンパイラであり、リソースコンパイラはresgenとそれぞれ分担が異なりますし他にもツールを使います。cscが役に立たないものというわけではなく、ソース間の依存関係なども考慮して適切な順でこれらのツールを呼び出すのがMSBuildです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
cscはMSBuildの一部だということですね。
何もわからないため、変な解釈をしてしまいました。
取っ掛かりはつかめましたので、少し勉強してみたいと思います。

ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

msbuildじゃダメですか？
`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe`辺りにあると思うんですが...
※上記pathはWin7のものです。pathはOSによって異なると思いますが、Vista以降だったらmsbuildを持ってると思います。

コマンドプロンプトを開き、slnファイルのあるdirへcdで移動。そこでMSBuild.exeを実行したらbuildできませんか？
※nugetする必要があるのでしたら、nugetは別途実行してやる必要があります。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
希望としては、勉強用として、IDEを頼らずにテキストエディタで
作成できるための手順を覚えたいとおもっています。
なので、途中までVisualStudioで作成してそこからコンパイルだけ…
というよりは、ゼロから作成する感覚で行きたいと。
MSBuildだと、slnファイルなども必要となってしまうということはないでしょうか。

すみません。こういったことも事前に記述するべきでした。

Comment: それであればsayuriさんの提案されている方法をお試しください。
CSC実行時に必要なオプションも全て出力されますよ。
ただし、実行コマンドが鬼のように長いので、オプションを変更後re-buildを実行。出力ウィンドウに出力される内容をテキストエディタなどにコピペして『Csc.exe』で検索してみてください。その1行がbuildに必要なコマンドです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
試してみますので、また躓くようならご助力を
お願いいたします。